# How can i add effect hover on span in <a>

Tags: css, hover

How can i add background for `<span>` when mouse hover `<span>` or `<a>`.

```
<a href="" class="special"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried so far. This is a trivial/standard task with CSS and with minimal effort you should be able to find the answer with a simple search of the CSS pesudo class `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is all about selecting elements. Here you want to select `span` when a parent `<a>` tag is hovered. Simply use `a:hover > span`.

```css
#activation:hover > #activated {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a id="activation" href="" class="special">
  <span id="activated" class="fa fa-facebook">?</span>
  <span>Facebook</span>
</a>
```